# What algebraic identities does the iteration of forcing operation satisfy?

Tags: set-theory, forcing, universal-algebra, boolean-algebras

Let $G$ be the set of all formulas $\phi(x)$ in the language of such that $ZFC\vdash\exists x\phi(x)$ exists, $ZFC\vdash\phi(x)\rightarrow``x\,\textrm{is a complete Boolean algebra}"$, $ZFC\vdash``\textrm{x and y are isomorphic Boolean algebras}"\rightarrow(\phi(x)\leftrightarrow\phi(y))$ and
$ZFC\vdash(\phi(x)\wedge\phi(y))\rightarrow``x\,\textrm{is isomorphic to}\,y"$.
As usual, if $ZFC\vdash\phi(x)\leftrightarrow\theta(x)$, then we should regard the formulas $\phi$ and $\theta$ as being equal.

Suppose now that $B$ is a complete Boolean algebra and $V^{B}\models\dot{C}\,\textrm{is a complete Boolean algebra}$. Then let $Z=\{\dot{c}\in V^{B}:\|\dot{c}\in\dot{C}\|=1\}$ and let $\simeq$ be the equivalence relation on $Z$ where $\dot{c}\simeq\dot{d}$ iff $\|\dot{c}=\dot{d}\|=1$. Then $Z/\simeq$ is a complete Boolean algebra where $[x]\wedge[y]=[z]$ if $z\in Z$ is an element where $\|z=x\wedge y\|=1$ and $[x]\vee[y]=[z]$ if $z$ is an element with $\|z=x\vee y\|=1$. Define $B*\dot{C}$ to be the complete Boolean algebra $Z/\simeq$.

Define an operation $\odot$ on $G$ where if $\phi,\theta\in G$, then $\phi\odot\theta$ is the formula in $G$ where if $V\models\phi(B)$ and $V^{B}\models\theta(\dot{C})$, then $V\models\phi\odot\theta(B*\dot{C})$. I am wondering about the algebraic properties that the countable algebra $(G,\odot)$ satisfies. In particular, I am interested in whether the operation $\odot$ satisfies any identities.

Does the operation $\odot$ satisfy any non-trivial identities? Does there exist some $\phi\in G$ so that $\langle\phi\rangle$ generates a free subalgebra of $G$? If so, then can $\phi$ be chosen in a nice way (i.e. so that for example $ZFC\vdash\phi(x)\rightarrow |x|\leq 2^{\aleph_{0}}$ or if $x$ has small enough complexity or if $\phi(x)$ determines a well known or easily definable Boolean algebra)?

Comment: The definition of $G$ should probably require that ZFC proves $\exists x\,\phi(x)$, because otherwise your $\odot$ operation won't be single-valued.

Comment: Andreas Blass. I have added the requirement $ZFC\vdash\exists x\phi(x)$.

Comment: Joseph, you haven't insisted that the formulas $\phi$ in $G$ respect isomorphisms of Boolean algebras. Thus, for example, if we let $\phi(x)$ assert that $x$ is the specific $2$-element Boolean algebra $\{0,1\}$, then it seems to me that the algebra $\langle\phi\rangle$ generated by $\phi$ will be free. Any generated expression will correspond essentially to a certain pattern of parentheses surrounding the trivial algebra and its corresponding names, and this pattern of parentheses will induce a unique readability, meaning the algebra is free. Is that right?

Comment: @Joel David Hamkins. I see. I attempted to specify that $\phi$ does respect isomorphisms in Boolean algebras, but I was missing a certain formula. Let me edit that.

Comment: Yes, your edit addresses that issue.

Comment: But now it will be associative, and so there won't be any fully free subalgebra (free in the term algebra sense). But one can hope for a free algebra modulo associativity.

Comment: I don't follow your first argument. If $\dot{C}$ necessarily forces that CH fails then CH will be false in $V^{B*\dot{C}}$ and $\phi$ will pick out a large Boolean algebra and $B*\dot{C}*\dot{D}$ will be large. Right?

Comment: Miha. I see. I will have to think about this some more and/or rewrite my comments.

Comment: As far as I can see Joel is right and $G$ is associative, making it a monoid with 2 being the neutral element. Another things to notice is that there is a formula $\theta(P)$ with a new predicate symbol $P$ such that for any $\phi\in G$ we have $\phi\odot\theta(\phi)=\theta(\phi)$; here $\theta(\phi)$ defines a big enough collapse to absorb whatever $\phi$ picks out.

Comment: It would be interesting to figure out what the centre of $G$ is. Is it trivial?

Comment: Perhaps some funny business is possible because you used isomorphism rather than forcing-equivalence (necessarily giving rise to the same forcing extensions) as the underlying equivalence. For example, a Boolean algebra $B$ is not isomorphic to an enormous lottery sum of copies of $B$, but these are forcing equivalent.